# Why am I getting spaces after every line in my python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I was solving this problem on a competitive coding site, and it is not accepting my answer, I figured this is because my output is giving space after every line.

I want to know why this space is coming and what I can do to change my code(Want to know what I am doing wrong.) so that it does not leave a line.

**Here's the problem:**

Mr. Vincent works in a door mat manufacturing company. One day, he designed a new door mat with the following specifications:

Mat size must be NxM. (N is an odd natural number, and M is 3 times N.)
The design should have 'WELCOME' written in the center.
The design pattern should only use |, . and - characters.

**Sample Designs:**

```
Size: 7 x 21 
---------.|.---------
------.|..|..|.------
---.|..|..|..|..|.---
-------WELCOME-------
---.|..|..|..|..|.---
------.|..|..|.------
---------.|.---------
```

**Input Format:**

A single line containing the space separated values of N and M.
Also, M is always 3 times N

**Output Format:**

Output the design pattern.

**This is my code:**

```
data = input().split()
height = int(data[0])
width = int(data[1])

pattern = ''

def methodA(times):
    print("-"*times,end = '')

def methodB(times):
    print(".|."*times, end = '')

inputDecrease = (width - 3)//2
inputIncrease = 1

#upperHalfStarts

for i in range(0, height//2 ):
    methodA(inputDecrease)
    methodB(inputIncrease)
    methodA(inputDecrease)
    print("\n")
    if not i == (height//2-1):
        inputDecrease -= 3
        inputIncrease += 2

#MiddleLineStarts

temp = (width -7)//2

methodA(temp)
print("WELCOME", end = '')
methodA(temp)
print("\n")

#lowerHalfStarts

for i in range(0, height//2):
    methodA(inputDecrease)
    methodB(inputIncrease)
    methodA(inputDecrease)
    print("\n")
    inputDecrease += 3
    inputIncrease -= 2
```

**This is my output:**

```
---------.|.---------

------.|..|..|.------

---.|..|..|..|..|.---

-------WELCOME-------

---.|..|..|..|..|.---

------.|..|..|.------

---------.|.---------
```

**Expected Output:**

```
---------.|.---------
------.|..|..|.------
---.|..|..|..|..|.---
-------WELCOME-------
---.|..|..|..|..|.---
------.|..|..|.------
---------.|.---------
```

Comment: Maybe `print("\n", end='')` or just `print()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print()` already includes a line break at the `end` of the line. Doing `print("\n")` means you print an explicit line break, plus the implicit one to end the output. You effectively run this:

```
print("\n", end="\n")
```

Use a plain `print()` instead, without the explicit newline.

Comment: I replaced all the print("\n") by print("") it works. Thanks!

Comment: Note that you can even use ``print()`` (without the empty string inside). Please accept the answer (the green checkmark) if it solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    # Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT
lstr = '.|.'
varbl=input().split()
midString = 'WELCOME'
breakpt = (int(varbl[0])-2)//2

for i in range(int(varbl[0])):

    print((lstr*((2*i)+1)).center(int(varbl[1]),'-'))
    if i == breakpt:
        print(midString.center(int(varbl[1]),'-'))
        break 
       
i = int(varbl[0])//2          
while i > 0:
    pattern = lstr * ((2 * i) - 1) 
    print (pattern.center (int(varbl[1]), '-')) 
    i = i-1
```